# How can I make a graph in graphviz with an edge from an external node to an internal one?

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to figure out how to make graphviz generate an image like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: As part of a larger graph, or stand-alone?  Is it OK to manually fiddle with intermediate results or must it be fully automated?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. Getting one node positioned intentionally on top of another
2. Getting the edge placed as specified
3. Getting the "B" label placed at the top of the node

The FAQ (https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) tells us how to achieve node and edge placement.  Label placement is done using newlines.  The code was hand-written.

```
digraph ontop {
  big [label="B\n\n\n\n" pos="2,2" shape=square height=1]
  little [label="A" pos="2,2" shape=square height=.4]
  big:e -> little:e
}
```

Command line:

```
neato -n -Tpng ontop.dot >ontop.png
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much. What resources would you recommend for getting to this level w/ GraphViz?

Comment: Read all the documentation on the Graphviz site & start searching stackoverflow.  But know that other tools may be better suited for general-purpose diagram creation.